# Why is the optimum space complexity of the answer O(n), when we are only storing all possible alphabets?

Tags: python, string, space-complexity

I have written a solution to the question: **"You are given a non-empty string, and a key, k which is a positive integer value. You are asked to shift each character in string by k values across according to the alphabet."**

For example, if `k=2` and `string = "abcd" -> "cdef"`. And we need to **wrap around the alphabet ** for any order greater than 'z'. i.e. if `string= "zzz"` and `k=2` then the **output** should be `"bbb"`.

My solution uses a dictionary to store the `ord()` of all characters in the alphabet, then for each character in `string` simply adds k to the order and returns the corresponding character from the dictionary:

```
def caesarCipherEncryptor(string, key):
    my_dict = dict()
    for i in range(97, 123):
        my_dict[ord(chr(i)) - ord("a")] = chr(i)

    res = ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        finder = (ord(string[i]) - ord("a")) + key
        while finder > 25:
            finder = finder % 26
        res += my_dict[finder]

    return res
```

The code above passes all test cases presented, so that is no issue. However,I am told that the optimum **space complexity** for this problem is `O(n)`, however by the way I have solved it in the above, is it not O(1)? Since I am simple storing all characters in the alphabet (max 26) in my dictionary?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332989/definition-of-space-complexity) answer your question? Your output is a list of size n.

Comment: size of string input is O(n)

Comment: Ohh I see, for some reason I didn't think a string would take up 'space' per se. But I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space complexity is `O(n)` because if there were more letters to the alphabet, or you were trying to extend this program you would have to insert all those letters too. Thus, for a problem space of n letters, you are using n bytes of space which means the space complexity is `O(n)`